# Is there a way to store a value in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, store, similarity

I want to use this case scenario in neo4j. Create a list of vsm values and compare this list to a knowed list, in order to compute a similarity.

This is the query i have:

```
MATCH (e:Event{value:'clickout item',step:'2'})
  <-[r2:CONTAIN]-(n:Session{id:"555"})-[r:HAS_ITEMS]->(im:Impression)
WITH collect(im.value) as listA, [1,19] as item  
RETURN [i in listA | CASE WHEN i IN item THEN 1 ELSE 0 END] as output
```

this has an output : [0 0 1 0 1 0 ]. Is there any way to compute in a single cypher query another vsm of different session and then compare it to the output using the Jaccard similarity?

All I have done by far, is creating kind of Cache node, but Jaccard similarity fails, as it is stored as a Node.

Comment: what is vsm? what is your error when Jaccard similarity fails? Can you give us an example and the expected result?

Comment: Vector space model. I want somehow to rewrite this query in order to calculate for each im.value= clickout and +1 step the [0 1 0 1 0 0 ] vector if item in list  item exists.